# How to sendRawTransaction when there is no update?

Tags: solidity

I can code sendRawTransaction when there is an update as follows:

```
var rawTransaction = {"from":myAddress,
"gasPrice":web3js.toHex(2*1e9),
"gasLimit":web3js.toHex(920000),
"to":contractAddress,
"data":contract.addWalletEmail.getData(wallet, emailaddress),
"nonce":nounceHex}

var transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction);
transaction.sign(privateKey);

var serializedTx = transaction.serialize();
web3js.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x'+serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err1, hash) {

});
```

But what do we code when there no update, eg checking a variable via a getter? Do we still sign the txn etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `sendRawTransaction()`, I assume you're using `web3` v0.2x.x (and not v1+).

For your version, you should use [`web3.eth.call(...)`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcall).

You don't have to sign the tx. Also, you don't spend gas on read-only calls (as long as you call them externally - not from a smart contract)

So, your code should look something like:
    //abi is the abi of your contract 
    var ctr = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

```
web3.eth.call({"from":myAddress,
       "to":contractAddress,
       "data":ctr.methods.getData(wallet, emailaddress),
      },  function(err1, hash) {

})
```

Comment: encodeABI - not needed. Otherwise works.

Comment: cool. I edited the post and removed that :)